# Jsp page getting called from cache rather than getting loaded from server

Tags: jsp, browser, caching

I am calling a jsp based on 2 parameters which is passed from jsp 1 in this way.Below i pass 2 parameters into 2.jsp and based on these 2 parameters data is displayed in 2.jsp.I have a loop in which i have a number of hrefs like the one i have described below.Each of these href passes a different set of value to 2.jsp.

```
out.println("<a href=\"2.jsp?prId=" + prog.getId() + count + "\">" + prog.getName() + "</a>");
```

I retrieve these 2 parameters in 2.jsp using the following lines

```
count_id = request.getParameter( "country_id" );
prog_id  = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter( "program_id" ));
```

Based on these 2 parameters i show the corresponding data in 2.jsp

Now i have a back button in 2.jsp and i call 1.jsp in 2.jsp using the following code

```
<a href="1.jsp"><img src="/image/back.gif" border="0"></a>
```

The problem is when i use the back button and go back to 1.jsp and select another href like the one i have described above i get the data related to the previous href selected.

I guess the problem is when i request the page is loaded from cache rather than from the server.
Please advice

Comment: did you check that the address is actually different?

Comment: what address???sme one plz suggest sth

Comment: The URL in the address bar on your second click.  Is it different from the one on your first click?  If no, then there is no problem.  You requested for the same page so you got the same page.

Comment: yes the url is changing because the value passed id different for different urls

Comment: each time the progid and count_id is different

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to instruct the browser to NOT cache the page. You can do this with help of a servlet filter which sets the following response headers:

```
@WebFilter("*.jsp")
public class NoCacheFilter implements Filter {

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;
        response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"); // HTTP 1.1.
        response.setHeader("Pragma", "no-cache"); // HTTP 1.0.
        response.setDateHeader("Expires", 0); // Proxies.
        chain.doFilter(req, res);
    }

    // ...
}
```

Now just map this filter on an URL pattern covering the JSP pages of interest. E.g. `*.jsp` or `/somefolder/*` (the `@WebFilter` in the example does that for all JSPs).

Make sure that you clear the browser cache before testing.

#### See also:

- [How to control web page caching, across all browsers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49547/making-sure-a-web-page-is-not-cached-across-all-browsers/2068407#2068407)

Comment: I have tried using this but this doesnt seem to work.I am using safari